# How to debug ASP.NET 4 with mono in VScode on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, mono

I just tried to debug a existing mono-ASP.NET 4-Project (in C#) in VScode.
Sadly it just does not work. Because I haven't got an idea, how to setup launch.json and taks.json to compile the ASP.NET project, to launch and finally to debug it.

Unfortunately there seems no documentation, how to setup VScode and its debugger, to run ASP.NET 4 projects based on/with mono.

Has anybody an idea, how to setup debugging and launching in VScode for ASP.NET 4 projects?

Comment: It's a preview release and will work with ASP.NET 5